# Can't choose first pokémon in Pokémon-GO

Tags: pokemon-go

I've just downloaded Pokémon-GO to my iPhone 6 Plus, but on the part where you have to choose your first Pokémon, my phone freezes but the home button still works. So it seems that it's just the app that is forzen.

[image]

How can I prevent this and get my first Pokémon?

Comment: Freezes as in not even the HOME button responds anymore, or more like the music stops and the screen won't update?

Comment: Just the Pokémon-GO app, not the home button

Comment: Can you check the app's permissions (on iOS)  Any of them set to deny?

Comment: No, I didn't deny any of them

Comment: Have you uninstalled the app and reinstalled it to see if that helped anything?

Comment: Ooooooooooooohhh... I should try that...

Comment: Yeah it worked!

Comment: @DrZoo you should post that as an answer

Comment: @TrolldéMage I couldn't yet because I didn't have enough rep, and the bonus "reputation rep" didn't count toward the 10 I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you uninstalled the app and reinstalled it to see if that helped anything? A reinstallation will wipe the files on the phone and get rid of any possible corrupt/broken files. The files will be fixed on redownload.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the app, it must be a launching error.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but it doesn't help...